# recycle vector values with data.table shift instead of padding with fill=NA

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to use the `shift` function from `data.table` to lead/lag a new column, but I would like to recycle values from the lagged vector that was added to the `data.table`. From what I can see, `fill must be a vector of length 1`, and so the values that are lagged must be populated with a constant value (ie `NA` here).

Please see the MWE below.

`dt1` is the resulting `data.table` using the `shift` function as is. The new `b` column has `NA` values where 4, 5, and 6 should be.

`dt2` is the desired data.table result. If my thinking is correct, the output requires `R` recycling rules but with a lead/lag value specified where the vector should begin.

I could have added a new vector (see below in `x_to_avoid`) but that requires more manual work that I hope to avoid.

Thanks,

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

# vector to lead/lag when updating datatable
x = c(1:6)

# leaves NA where 4, 5, 6 "should" have gone for my purposes
dt1 <- data.table(a = c(1:10)) %>% 
  .[, b := shift(x,
                 n = 3L,
                 fill = NA,
                 type = c("lag"))]
dt1

# desired output
dt2 <- dt1[, .(a)] %>% 
  .[, b := c(4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1)]

# could use another vector, but my actual use is more complicated and I prefer to avoid this (if possible)
x_to_avoid = c(4,5,6,1:6,1)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could define your own function, something like `shift2 <- function(x, n, type = "lag") if(type == "lag") c(tail(x, -(length(x) - n)), head(x, -n)) else c(tail(x, -n), head(x, -(length(x) - n)))`. Then you could do `dt1 <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = shift2(x, n = 3L))`. Though `n` here isn't vectorized like in `data.table::shift`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for that. Was not familiar with `head` and `tail` function. Also didn't know about defining a function without `{` parenthesis! Speed is not a big issue here as it is a one-off and I will likely create a CSV file to load from (and so others can use it). This is awesome, thanks! If you post it as an answer I will mark it correct (if you want)...

Comment: I wouldn't make some hack as an official data.table answer. I think you could perhaps add a feature request on the [GH issues](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) page instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [binhf::shift](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/binhf/versions/1.0-3/topics/shift) does the job. First you will need to lengthen the vector using `rep.len` and then you can cycle it using `binhf::shift`. I have no idea about the performance though.